# A Generic error occures when saving images using WebService

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, asmx, web-hosting

I have developed a WebService application in C# for Upload 5kb jpeg images to it's direcotry. 
When I run my WebService in Somee.com it's worked fine and I can upload files using that webservice. but Recently my partner provided me a Webhosting account from his dedicated server and I uploaded the webservice to it , the webservice works fine except webmethods that used to upload images.  When I try to upload images it always give me the following error

```
Server was unable to process request.-->  A generic error occured in GDI+
```

WebMethod takes a BiteArray of the image as an argument and then It convert the bite array back to an Image then It create a NewInstance of that image and Dispose the previous one. and next it saves image to a Folder called "MyFileUploads" located in WebService directory.

Please tell me why i am getting this error and a way to fix it. Any help will be very apreciated.

Comment: Check write folder rights.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed the permission of the directory that I save images to.  And that's helped me 
I just granted read/write permission to the directory that I save images to.

Answer (score 1):

According to this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms533798(v=vs.85).aspx GDI+ is not supposed to be used in a service environment. This could explain the error you are getting. The .NET Image class is basically a wrapper for the windows GDI+ API.

As for a solution, you have two options:

1) You do not mention that you are doing any sort of image manipulation, you are simply saving the image to a directory. Have you tried simply saving the array of bytes to the output file directly?

2) If you need to process the image, try using a third party imaging library that does not use GDI+. I have found https://code.google.com/p/aforge/ to be pretty good for this sort of thing.